# Setting up MS Tests 2010 on TeamCity?

Tags: mstest, teamcity

I've recently installed VS 2010 Ultimate, and decided to move a project to TeamCity, The project contains a few *.dlls with unit tests inside.

In VS 2008 the setup procedure, at the build runner stage, would consist of :

- Setting the path to the *.sln file
- Setting the VS version (2008)
- Setting the target(s) such as : "Clean Build"
- Setting the configuration such as : "Debug"
- Setting the platform sucha as : "any cpu"
- Checking the "Enable MSTest tests" checkbox
- Setting the path to MSTest.exe (pickable from the list of shortcuts)
- Listing the assembly files : (1st one beging the dll called : Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.MSBuildTasks.dll)
- Picking the MSTest *.trx test results file

In VS2010 the forementioned dll file is gone, and I'm unable to setup the MSTests, does anyone have a recipe how to do that?

edit : replaced config file with the *.trx file line

Comment: what version of teamcity were these steps outlined for?

Comment: In order to get it to work for me, I also had to make sure I had vs2010 installed also on the same machine where teamcity was set to run from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am currently using MSTest with VS2010 on TeamCity and the tests are working perfectly. These are the only steps I had to do for the MSTest part:

- Checking the "Enable MSTest tests" checkbox
- Setting the path to MSTest.exe (pickable from the list of shortcuts)
- Listing the assembly files

I did not have to select the .trx test results file or add Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.MSBuildTasks.dll to the list of assemblies, and all of the other fields in the 'MSTest Settings' section are empty.

Comment: Correct, I've solved this a loooong time ago, completely fogotten about the question - but you still get credit. :)

Comment: instead of listing all the test assemblies, is there a way to tell teamcity to run any test DLL? Run all tests, please?

Comment: where is the "Enable MSTest tests" and the other settings you mention Marty?